# Try/Catch doesn't activate on an error trying to open excel Workbook

Tags: java, excel, error-handling, apache-poi

Using apache-POI to open an excel workbook or create one if it is non-existant.
Due to some reason the workbook that was being opened was corrupt, causing an error to occur on the line annotated with the error comment.

Somehow the try/catch around this section of code didn't seem to activate. Any ideas why, and how I could properly handle these kinds of errors?
Additionally, is there any way to check the integrity of a file during my `if(file.exists() && file.length() != 0) {` conditional?

```
public XSSFWorkbook OpenWB(String directory, String name) {
      File file = new File(directory + "\\" + name + ".xlsx");
      FileInputStream fIP;

      if(file.exists() && file.length() != 0) {
        try {
            fIP = new FileInputStream(file);
            //Get the workbook instance for XLSX file 
             workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fIP); //*********error occurs here**********
             fIP.close();
             System.out.println(name + ".xlsx file open successfully.");
             return workbook;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
             System.out.println("Error to open " + name + ".xlsx file, creating blank");
              //Create Blank workbook
              workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
              Integer i = 0;
              while (file.isFile() && file.exists()) {
                  name = name.concat(i.toString());
                  file = new File(directory + "\\" + name + ".xlsx");
                  i++;
              }
              return workbook;
        }
      } else {
         System.out.println("Error to open " + name + ".xlsx file, creating blank");
          //Create Blank workbook
          workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
          return workbook;
      }
}
```

Comment: whats the exception you get ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this piece of code and it will give you an error
**"Error to open random.xlx file, creating blank"** which means your try catch is working. you forgot to initialize your variable "workbook" it seems.

```
      package stackoverflow;
      import java.io.File;
      import java.io.FileInputStream;
      import java.io.IOException;

      import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

      public class Solution {
      public XSSFWorkbook OpenWB(String directory, String name) {
      File file = new File(directory + "\\" + name + ".xlsx");
      FileInputStream fIP;

      XSSFWorkbook workbook;
     if(file.exists() && file.length() != 0) {
        try {
            fIP = new FileInputStream(file);
            //Get the workbook instance for XLSX file 
             workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fIP); //*********error occurs here**********
             fIP.close();
             System.out.println(name + ".xlsx file open successfully.");
             return workbook;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
             System.out.println("Error to open " + name + ".xlsx file, creating blank");
              //Create Blank workbook
              workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
              Integer i = 0;
              while (file.isFile() && file.exists()) {
                  name = name.concat(i.toString());
                  file = new File(directory + "\\" + name + ".xlsx");
                  i++;
              }
              return workbook;
        }
      } else {
         System.out.println("Error to open " + name + ".xlsx file, creating blank");
          //Create Blank workbook
          workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
          return workbook;
      }
}  
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Solution s = new Solution();
    s.OpenWB("D://", "random.xlx");
}
 }
```

you can modify the Solution class part as per your needs.